# How add https to docker container as default rather than http?

Tags: docker, http, https, docker-compose, rancher

I lauched docker container using Rancher 2 and when i click on its URL it takes me to http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:32000

But i would like is : it takes me to directly to https://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:32000  (https instead of http).

How can i do that ?

Any help would appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I see `32000` in the URL, I am assuming you had used NodePort to expose your application. If you are using Rancher 2.x, you would be able to take advantage of `Ingress`. You can expose your app using port 433 by providing your SSL certificates and the ingress controller automatically does the redirect for you. This is similar behavior provided by Load Balancers in various cloud providers.

If you want to do it in your app, you should be able to add logic in your http/https action handler code where you can do a redirect from http to https.

Comment: Yes, i am using NodePort to expose the container, but i don't know how to use ingress and generating the certificate, could you please elaborate more ?

Comment: @Mohamed You can find a sample example here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls